# react remove item from array of object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

i have a cart item in localstorage

```
const cart = [
  {_id: 'abcd1234', productName: 'product1', price: '100'},
  {_id: 'abcd12345', productName: 'product2', price: '200'},
  {_id: 'abcd123456', productName: 'product3', price: '150'},
  {_id: 'abcd1234567', productName: 'product4', price: '175'},
];
```

and mapping it to display a cart item, with button to remove an item

```js
<Container>
      <div>
      {
        cart.map(item => (
        <p>item.productName</p>
        <p>item.price</p>
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt mr-1" style={{ color: '#ff6b6b' }} onClick={removeProduct}></i>
))
      }
      </div>
</Container>
```

this my function to remove

```js
  const removeProduct = () => {
    const cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartProduct"));
    let indexToRemove = 1;
    cart.splice(indexToRemove, 1)
    localStorage.setItem("cartProduct", JSON.stringify(cart));
    window.location.reload();
 };
```

Every time I try to remove a product2, product 3 or product4, what is removed is the previous product. For example, I want to remove product4, so what is removed is product3.

When there is one product left, it cannot be deleted at all. Could you help me? thanks

Comment: `let indexToRemove = 1;`  don't you think that index should be related to the item you want to remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the index of the current item to `removeProduct` function so that it will know which item to be removed.

```
<Container>
  <div>
    {
      cart.map((item, index) => ({
        <p>item.productName</p>
        <p>item.price</p>
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt mr-1" style={{ color: '#ff6b6b' }} onClick={() => this.removeProduct(index)}></i>
      ))
    }
  </div>
</Container>
```

And on `removeProduct` function, you have to delete the item in the `index` position.

```
const removeProduct = (indexToRemove) => {
    const cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartProduct"));
    cart.splice(indexToRemove, 1)
    localStorage.setItem("cartProduct", JSON.stringify(cart));
    window.location.reload();
};
```

Comment: I think your `onClick` syntax is incorrect ~ https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers

Answer (score 1):

change removeproduct code as below. and pass product-id in function as parameter.

```
const removeProduct = (productId) => {
    let cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartProduct"));
    cart = cart.filter(productData => productData._id !== productId)
    localStorage.setItem("cartProduct", JSON.stringify(cart));
    window.location.reload();
 };
```

for more details on `filter` method refer MDN docs.

change your component as below to pass id parameter to function.

```
<Container>
      <div>
      {
        cart.map(item => (
         <p>item.productName</p>
         <p>item.price</p>
         <i
          class="fas fa-trash-alt mr-1"
          style={{ color: '#ff6b6b' }}
          onClick={() => removeProduct(item._id)}
         ></i>
        ))
      }
      </div>
</Container>
```

Comment: Would be great if you showed how to _"pass product-id in function as parameter"_